# ioprio_set is not showing gain in io performace of calling thread

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, io

This small experiment was to demonstrate the gain in I/O performance by increasing I/O priority of thread . 
For this purpose [ioprio_set](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ioprio_set) system call was used.
To see this api in action you can explore code of ionice utility.
So, I have spawned some threads to copy some files of same size(where one thread copy one file to some output file) 
and for one thread I have called ioprio_set.

```
ioprio_set(IOPRIO_WHO_PROCESS, 0, IOPRIO_PRIO_VALUE(IOPRIO_CLASS_RT,0));
```

These parameter are such that it will escalate the priority of calling thread to real time(ioclass) with highest value(i.e 0). And for measurement of performance I have used the clock_gettime around io operations of threads.

But after running program I can't see the gain in execution time calling thread. 
Following is the code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/syscall.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<time.h>
#define NB_THREADS  3 
#define IOPRIO_PRIO_VALUE(class, data)  (((class) << IOPRIO_CLASS_SHIFT) | data)
#define IOPRIO_CLASS_SHIFT  13
#define BILLION  1000000000L

enum {
    IOPRIO_CLASS_NONE,
    IOPRIO_CLASS_RT,
    IOPRIO_CLASS_BE,
    IOPRIO_CLASS_IDLE,
};

enum {
    IOPRIO_WHO_PROCESS = 1,
    IOPRIO_WHO_PGRP,
    IOPRIO_WHO_USER,
};

static inline int ioprio_set(int which, int who, int ioprio)
{
    return syscall(SYS_ioprio_set, which, who, ioprio);
}


double times[NB_THREADS];
void *copyfile(void *args){
    struct timespec start, stop;
    double accum;


int x;
    char finname[10];// name of the file to be copied
    char foutname[10],ch;
    int *id;
    FILE *source, *target;


    id = (int *) args;
    sprintf(finname,"large%d.txt",*id);

    sprintf(foutname,"out%d.txt",*id);

    if(*id == 2){
        x=ioprio_set(IOPRIO_WHO_PROCESS, 0, IOPRIO_PRIO_VALUE(IOPRIO_CLASS_RT,0));
        //printf("##%d##",x);
    }

if( clock_gettime( CLOCK_REALTIME, &start) == -1 ) {
        perror( "clock gettime" );
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    //printf("%s##%s\n\n",finname,foutname);
    source = fopen(finname, "r");
    if( source == NULL )
    {
        printf("Press any key to exit...\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    target = fopen(foutname, "w");

    if( target == NULL )
    {
        fclose(source);
        printf("Press any key to exit...\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while( ( ch = fgetc(source) ) != EOF )
    {
        fputc(ch, target);           
    }

    //printf("\ndone copying file %s to %s in %lf\n",finname,foutname,accum);

    fclose(source);
    fclose(target);
    if( clock_gettime( CLOCK_REALTIME, &stop) == -1 ) {
        perror( "clock gettime" );
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    accum = ( stop.tv_sec - start.tv_sec )
        + (double)( stop.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec )
        / (double)BILLION;

    times[*id]=accum;
}




int main()
{

    unsigned int ints[NB_THREADS],i;
    int err;
    pthread_t    threads[NB_THREADS];

    for (i = 0; i < NB_THREADS; ++i) {
        ints[i] = i;
        err=pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, copyfile , &ints[i]);
        if (err != 0)
            printf("\ncan't create thread :[%s]", strerror(err));
        else
            printf("\n Thread %d created successfully\n",i);

        //pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < NB_THREADS; ++i) {
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < NB_THREADS; ++i) {
        printf("\n %d : %lf",i,times[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

*Note* : to call this api with IOPRIO_CLASS_RT, permissions are needed. (So already ran with sudo). ioprio_set is returning 0(successful call, it return -1 in case of failure).
*Note* : to compile this code add -lpthread and -lrt to gcc.

**Q**. Is some thing wrong with code structure.?
**Q**. How can I carry out this experiment correctly?
**Q**. What can be done to achieve desired thing i.e increasing i/o priority of thread over other threads?

Comment: How did you profile? Values? Expectation? Other relevant circumstances? **What** restricts performance?

Comment: Most likely the contents of the file is already in page cache, in which case the I/O priority won't have much effect. Make sure the `large#.txt` files are separate and not hardlinks to the same inode: if they point to the same inode, then there is only one instance of the contents; whenever a block of the file gets cached into page cache, the other threads get it immediately. Finally, if there is no competition over I/O resources, the priority has no effect, so do make sure the threads compete (and not over the same inode). To clear page cache: `sudo sh -c 'echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches'`.

Comment: I took care that large#.txt are not hardlink of same inode, In fact I have generated each file with with 'base64 /dev/urandom | head -c 3000000000 > large#.txt' (3GB file)

I have also tried freeing caches anyways.
output was : (Gain in 2nd thread is not seen)

 Thread 0 created successfully

 Thread 1 created successfully

 Thread 2 created successfully

 0 : 347.382835
 1 : 350.225743
 2 : 349.463542